# Where is the bug in my Code

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures

I'm a beginner . I was trying to learn the usage of optional 3rd parameter of sort() function . I tried to apply this to sort numbers from 1 to 1000 according to their number of divisors in an ascending order .

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct data {
    int index;
    int divisor;
}a[1001];

bool sortbydivisor (const data &lhs,const data &rhs)
{
    return lhs.divisor <rhs.divisor;
}

int number_of_divisors(int n)
{
    int r=0;
    for (int i=1;i*i<=n;i++)
    {
        if (n%i==0)
        {
            if (i*i!=n)
            {
                r+=2;
            }
        else 
            {
                r+=1;
            }
    }
}

return r;
}

int main ()
{
    int i,t,x;
    for (i=1;i<=1000;i++)
    {
        a[i].index=i;
        a[i].divisor=number_of_divisors(i);
    }

    sort(a+1,a+10001,sortbydivisor);

    scanf("%d",&t);

    for (i=1;i<=t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        printf("Case %d: %d\n",i,a[x].index);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After compiling i didn't get any error . But after running it I got this warning "the program stopped working" . In online compilers it says "runtime error" :( . why ?

Thanks in advance for your help :) .

Comment: You're initialising one thousand entries in your array, but trying to sort **ten** thousand.

Comment: You should start your first loop with i = 0, so you don t have a[0] undefined, and it make your call to sort easier to understand, also, I think a + 10001 is a little too much, there is a 0 too much. @Mike: Arr, 4seconds too late.

Comment: Consider using `#define ARRAY_SIZE 1000`, then using this #define in your array initializer and in your loops.  (You have learned why magic numbers are a Bad Thing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've given an invalid upper bound, so `sort` is trying to move nonexistent objects after the end of the array. You want

```
sort(a+1,a+1001,sortbydivisor);  // not 10001
```

In C++11, there are handy library functions to avoid mistakes like this:

```
sort(std::begin(a) + 1, std::end(a), sortbydivisor);
```

noting that `begin` needs bodging slightly due to the one-based indexing. If you can't use a C++11 library, they are easy to write yourself:

```
template <typename T, size_t N> T * begin(T (&a)[N]) {return a;}
template <typename T, size_t N> T * end  (T (&a)[N]) {return a+N;}
```

Comment: Thanks for everything :)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know but if you compile and run in debug you should be able to get a call stack to determine where your program failed and that should give you the information where your program is failing.

Just a note, you are using your indices inconsistently (ending at 1000) in your initializing loop and 10001 in the sort algorithm.  This is out of bounds of your array.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> sort(a+1,a+10001,sortbydivisor);
> ```

Silly typo!

Comment: Yeah .. Verry silly :(